# Thread was being aborted while sending mail using smtp after configuring timeout in web.config

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to send mail through website; the mail was successfully sent, still this exception is thrown:

> Thread was being aborted

Here is the C# code:

```
try
{
    MailAddress mailFrom = new MailAddress("info@mydomain.org");
    MailAddress mailTo = new MailAddress("mygmailid@gmail.com");
    MailMessage MainMessage = new MailMessage(mailFrom, mailTo);
    MainMessage.Subject = "BloggersFolder: Answer received";
    MainMessage.CC.Add("anothergmailid@gmail.com");
    MainMessage.Priority = MailPriority.High;
    MainMessage.Body = "Hello - this is body message";
    SmtpClient smtpclient = new SmtpClient("relay-hosting.secureserver.net", 25);

    smtpclient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtpclient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("info@mydomain.org", "mypassword");
    smtpclient.Send(MainMessage);

    Response.Redirect("~/thank-you.aspx?page=answer");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    string strg = ex.Message.ToString();

    Response.Redirect("~/thank-you.aspx?page="+ strg);
    ex = null;
}
```

I already configured http timeout (found solution somewhere else), still the error is thrown.

`web.config`:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout = "60"/>
</system.web>
```

Comment: Requesting to the excellent person to give the reason to mark it negative

Answer (score 2):

You need to change your `Response.Redirect` to **not** abort the thread - use this:

```
Response.Redirect("~/thank-you.aspx?page=answer", false);
```

With this second parameter `false`, no running thread will be aborted, and no `ThreadAbortException` happens ...